# Binding 2 data sets with different number of rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 single column datasets but dataset A has fewer rows than dataset B.

I am trying to create a second data frame with 2 columns combining the 2 datasets. Something like this:

```
A <- data.frame(A=c('x','y','z'))
B <- data.frame(B=c('a','b','c','d','e'))
```

I need to combine both to create the dataframe bellow,(repeating all elements of A until the next...):

```
C <- data.frame(C=c('x','x','x','x','x','y','y','y','y','y','z','z','z','z','z'),D=c('a','b','c','d','e'))
```

The original datasets are much larger than this so I am trying to figure out an easy way to do it.

Comment: `merge(A, B)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is `crossing` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
crossing(A, B)
```

Answer (score 2):

In `base` we can use `exapnd.grid`:

```r
expand.grid(A$A,B$B)
```